# can you format an enumerated list?

Tags: python, format, tuples

I am trying to use .replace and .lstrip on an enumerated list. is there a workaround since it doesnt seem to work on tuples?

```
for file in onlyfiles:#for file in current directory
with fitz.open(file) as doc: #open the file
    text="" #create a blank text variable
    for page in doc: # for each page in the file
        text += page.get_text() # add the text from the page to the blank text block
        text_1 = re.split('\.(?![0-9])', text)
    #print(text_1)    

    words = ['increase','growth']
    
    print(f'File name: {file}')
    
    for word in words:
        print(f'Keyword: {word.title()}')
        print('')
        sentences = [sentence for sentence in text_1 if word.lower() in sentence.lower()]
        
        for sentence in enumerate(sentences, start=1):
            print(sentence)
            print('')
```

[Example of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqyGr.png)

I would like to be able to remove newline characters. When i added to the print(sentence) line, it told me tuples have no object replace.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but you can try to play with `for i, sentence in enumerate(...):` inside your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  First of all, please fix your formatting.  Formatting your code correctly is critical with Python, as indentation determines behavior.  As it is now, your code is not syntactically correct and would fail to run.  Next, can you supply some sample input and output to illustrate the behavior you desire?

Comment: @cryptofool I am not sure the issue - when i run this in my console I get output and i believe it is formatted correctly. I will edit the post with an image and explain more what I am looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `sentence` is a tuple with two elemens and you can always do `number, text = sentence` and later work with `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enumerate(iterable, start) function will return a sequence of tuples. If we loop through that sequence normally like this, we get a tuple on each iteration:

```
for t in enumerate(iterable):
print(t) #t is a tuple
```

But the syntax we showed above unpacks that tuple on each iteration, so:

```
for a, b in enumerate(iterable):
print(a) #first value in the tuple (the count)
print(b) #second value in the tuple (the item in the original iterable)
```

Comment: hai thanks for giving points. This point means a lot to me, and i hope my answer can help you to break the problem